# Passing data between activities in Android(BIG JSON DATA STRING)

Tags: android, json, android-intent

How can I pass an big json-string between activities fast?

**a) My Activity one look like this.**

```
JsonDataTask jdt = new JsonDataTask(c);

AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> rdataJSON = jdt.execute("https://job.jobnet.dk/FindJobService/V1/Gateway.ashx/annonce?fritekst=akutjob&sortering=match");

try {   
   Intent i = new Intent(c, JoblistActivity.class);
   i.putExtra("rdataJSON", rdataJSON.get());
   startActivity(i);
} catch (InterruptedException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
} catch (ExecutionException e1) {
   e1.printStackTrace();
}
```

**b) Then Activity two below.**

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
JobPosting_json = intent.getStringExtra("rdataJSON");
```

The problem is where the 'jdt.execute()' a.k.a json-string
return too must data.. 
Then the 'getStringExtra("rdataJSON")' can´t holde the hule string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So two solutions:

- or you cache the data in your first activity then get it in the second
- or you do the request in the second activity

I usually go for the second option but it all depends on your requirements.

Comment: hmm if I use 2 option then the 'ProgressDialog' in the 'AsyncTask'-class do not show before swith to activity to.

Comment: well you can start the activity which start an asynctask with its progress dialog

Comment: Ok I just use option one, for this.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use Parcelable class to one activity to another, Refer http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html

Comment: It is not good approach for big data. Parcelable allow to pass data no more than 1mb, but on some platforms no more than 512kb. It is not so many. If you trying to pass more than possible, your application will crash with TransactionTooLarge exception.